# How to use column from main query in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Invoice with a column total.  Then I have a table Payments with a column amount (Usually there are several payments to one invoice).  I need a column balance which is the difference of Invoice.Total - (total of payments made on that invoice). This is what I have (Oh ya using Azure Sql Server)

```
select I.Invoice_Id, 
       I.Total - (select sum(Amount) from Payments P
                  where I.Invoice_Id = P.Invoice_Id) as Balance,
       Q.Quote_Id,
       Q.Description,
       Q.Vendor_Num
from Invoice as I
    inner join Payments as P on I.Invoice_Id = P.Invoice_Id
    inner join Quote as Q on Q.Quote_Id = I.Quote_Id;
```

Eventually this will be a view showing what invoices have balance owed.  If I remove the where in the sub query it gives me an answer but it is the sum of all payments.  I just want the sum of payments made on that invoice.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question?  Your query would seem to be okay.

Comment: A general tip, don't re-use the same table alias in the sub-query as in the main query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two approaches to this. You could either subquery or group by. If you're doing a subquery you don't need the table in the main query. Also the inner join to Payments would mean that invoices without payment would not be returned by the query. Changing it to a left outer join in the Group By example will return NULL rows when the `I.Invoice_Id = P.Invoice_Id` is not met.

Group By:

```
SELECT I.Invoice_Id, 
       I.Total - sum(ISNULL(P.Amount,0)) AS Balance,
       Q.Quote_Id,
       Q.Description,
       Q.Vendor_Num
  FROM Invoice AS I
  JOIN Quote AS Q on Q.Quote_Id = I.Quote_Id
  LEFT JOIN Payments AS P on I.Invoice_Id = P.Invoice_Id
 GROUP BY I.Invoice_Id, I.Total, Q.Quote_Id, Q.Description, Q.Vendor_Num
```

Subquery:

```
SELECT I.Invoice_Id, 
       I.Total - (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Payments P WHERE P.Invoice_Id = I.Invoice_Id) AS Balance,
       Q.Quote_Id,
       Q.Description,
       Q.Vendor_Num
  FROM Invoice AS I
  JOIN Quote AS Q on Q.Quote_Id = I.Quote_Id
```

Comment: Steve you are an sql monster....Copy pasted group by option into new query and boom got exactly what I was looking for.  Just to be complete I tried sub query option and it worked perfectly also.  I like that you included the isnull option but I don't create an invoice until payment has been made that's how a quote becomes an invoice. I am going to try to figure out how to mark this as the answer....Thanks again

Comment: Trying to figure this out, so you group by everything except the aggregate function sum.  And if you do a sub query you don't join the table in the sub query.  Thanks again

Comment: Exactly. If you're using any aggregate function (Max, Min, Avg, Sum, etc) you need to group by all other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your query is returning multiple results (duplicates per payment) since you are `joining` on the `payments` table.

One option would be to just remove that `join` to the `payments` table. Here's an alternative option which moves the `correlated subquery` to a `join`:

```
select I.Invoice_Id, 
       I.Total - p.SumAmount as Balance,
       Q.Quote_Id,
       Q.Description,
       Q.Vendor_Num
from Invoice as I
    inner join Quote as Q on Q.Quote_Id = I.Quote_Id;
    inner join (
        select invoice_id, sum(amount) SumAmount
        from Payments
        group by invoice_id) as P on I.Invoice_Id = P.Invoice_Id
```

Comment: Tried this got an error ====  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. ===== I really appreciate your help...Steve above's answer worked but I really thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mark -- my guess is the `;` in there -- just remove it... glad your problem is resolved nonetheless...